QGIS custom CRS definition error
Using QGIS 3.28.4 on Windows 10
We have a local coordinate system at our site at work, and I am trying to create a custom CRS for it. It is needed, because I have some geotiff raster images that are in this local CRS, but my QGIS project needs to be in a known CRS, eg. EPSG:3016.
I know the local CRS´s "relation" to a known CRS in QGIS (EPSG:3016): "translation" on both the X and Y axes, rotation around the Z axis and scaling. After some research I have created this WKT string:
DERIVEDPROJCRS["Aitik Lokala",
BASEPROJCRS["SWEREF99 20 15",
    BASEGEOGCRS["SWEREF99",
        DATUM["SWEREF99",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4619]],
    CONVERSION["SWEREF99 20 15",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",20.25,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",150000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
DERIVINGCONVERSION["Aitik Lokala",
    METHOD["Similarity transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9621]],
    PARAMETER["Ordinate 1 of evaluation point in target CRS",7445508.21,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8621]],
    PARAMETER["Ordinate 2 of evaluation point in target CRS",172234.52,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8622]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor for source CRS axes",1,
        SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
        ID["EPSG",1061]],
    PARAMETER["Rotation angle of source CRS axes",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8614]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["northing (N)",north,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["easting (E)",east,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["Mine local coordinate system"],
    AREA["Aitik Mine, Norrbotten, Sweden"],
    BBOX[63.45,16.08,69.07,23.28]]]

What I did was that I copied the WKT of EPSG:3016, then added the "DERIVINGCONVERSION" part and other minor corrections. The actual parameters are still probably wrong, I have to explore with trial-and-error which axis is which and if I need positive or negative values. But here comes the problem: although QGIS says its a valid WKT string, if I set it to a raster layer that is in the local CRS, it just disappears. I tried switching the parameters (x-y axes), or leaving the actual values at 0, but no matter what I do, if I set the custom CRS for the layer, it disappears, so I can't even do my trial-and-error.
"Zoom to layer" zooms back to the place where the raster was visible before changing to the custom CRS, no matter what parameters I use for translation. It looks like as if it won't actually do anything (except making it invisible).
Can someone tell me what can possibly be wrong with the WKT string, or if the error lies somewhere else?
Edit: If I set the project CRS to my custom, then the layer on that custom CRS appears ("in the same place" on Canvas), but the other layer with the recognised CRS (EPSG:3016) disappears. Changing back the project CRS to EPSG:3016 (or any other recognised), things reverst, layer on custom CRS invisible, layer on any other recognised CRS visible.
Edit2: When adding the custom CRS in QGIS, validation says that the WKT is valid, still, if I test it with latitude 64/ longitude 17 (within the BBOX of the EPSG:3016), I get the following error:
"forward transform of (inf, inf) Error: Fallback transform failed"

Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! Your system is translating 7446 km in North and 172 km in East, so it is probaby going out of the scope bounding box. Remove the usage node of the definition. Also, do you have two pairs of coordinates in source and destination reference frames to derive the parameters of the transformation?

@GabrielDeLuca Deleting the BBOX row does not help. Also, I have another ortofoto about the same area on canvas, with CRS EPSG:3016 and the same BBOX. I would expect the layer with the custom CRS to line up to that, so the BBOX should not be a problem in my understanding.  I don't have a pair of coordinates, I only got info from another engineering team how much they translate/rotate/scale their cad files when they get drawings in different CRS's.

But you are translating the CRS, not the drawing. Did you tried negative values for the parameters?

Yes, I tried both positive/negative values and even switching axes. Tried also using 0 values for all derivingconversion parameters (except for scaling, that was 1), to see if it is even visible without any "movement", but no. Even tried two other conversion methods, but just nothing works. I have a feeling that it is something with my WKT string itself that I did wrong.

Regards the WKT, I usually use affine parametric without any problem. It is more generic affine (like a 2d polynomial order 1 transformation) so skew can be applied, but if you only want the translations (A0 and B0 parameters), I know it works. I usually remove the USAGE node, and do not change the name of the DERIVINGCONVERSION, just change the DERIVEDPROJCRS name.

So, this was driving me nuts for two weeks, but finally: it's working!
There were several things that I needed to get right:
#1: Updated to QGIS 3.34.4 (custom crs creation in the earlier version was buggy as hell - it still is, but now it's at least not making all layers on custom crs's invisible. Maybe it would work with the perfect WKT, I haven't tested that)
#2: Needed to use the Similarity transformation (EPSG:9621) as @mkennedy suggested
#3: Noticed that my raster image was mirrored after transformation, so I changed the "easting" to "westing" in the CS/AXIS sektion in the WKT string like this:
    CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["Y",north,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["X",west,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

I don't really understand why this is needed, since our local crs axes are directed the same way as the base crs (first "up", second "to the right"), but it works so I don't care XD
#4: I realized that the transformation method needs the coordinates of the origin of the source crs in the target crs, but I got numbers the other way around. But once I calculated the right translations, my images are lining up perfectly.
Links of docs that helped me with all of this:
Document on EPSG transformation methods
Document on WKT representation of CRS
The full working WKT:
DERIVEDPROJCRS["Aitik Lokala",
BASEPROJCRS["SWEREF99 20 15",
    BASEGEOGCRS["SWEREF99",
        DATUM["SWEREF99",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4619]],
    CONVERSION["SWEREF99 20 15",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",20.25,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",150000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
DERIVINGCONVERSION["Aitik Lokala",
    METHOD["Similarity transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9621]],
    PARAMETER["Ordinate 1 of evaluation point in target CRS",7224495.9764,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8621]],
    PARAMETER["Ordinate 2 of evaluation point in target CRS",-1808659.5991,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8622]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor for source CRS axes",0.99999400004,
        SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
        ID["EPSG",1061]],
    PARAMETER["Rotation angle of source CRS axes",-77.27,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8614]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["Y",north,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["X",west,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["Mine local coordinate system"],
    AREA["Aitik Mine, Norrbotten, Sweden"]]]


Please provide the full working WKT.

@AndreaGiudiceandrea Added to my answer

Great job! I'm glad my suggestion was helpful even if I couldn't give you the exact parameters you needed.

Coordinate frame method and its parameters are in XYZ, 3D geocentric space, while your parameters are part of a 2D conformal, or similarity, transformation--they're applied to the easting, northing values of a projected coordinate system. Take a look at EPSG's Similarity transformation, 9621.
Note: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Parameter Dataset.

I tried your suggested transformation in QGIS 3.10.10 (that's what I have at home), and the problem persist. If I change the CRS of the layer to my custom CRS, the layer disappears. "Zoom to layer" zooms to the same place on canvas where it was, no matter how I combine the parameter values. One addition: If I change the project CRS to the custom CRS, the layer with the custom CRS appears, and the other one with the known CRS disappears. Still, both are "in the same place" on canvas. I also edited the question with the new WKT string with your suggested transformation.
